# height: 100% background sidebar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, height, sidebar

how can I add background height: 100% for aside?

```css
aside,
.side-nav {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

How can I fix the sidebar (aside)?

Comment: can you add the html that you are using? for try to help

Comment: Trust me, it has a parent. If you're doing it right the _"minimum"_ it would be is `<body>`.

Comment: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Percentage height requires that the parent have a height set on it. The height can be set with any unit of measurement, but needs to be set.

Comment: Define position to be absolute. Then set height (and width) as desired.

Comment: I added html to post

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can actually use the "vh" designation (based on viewport height).

For your example, you would just add "height: 100vh" to your css.

Comment: The OP likely wants the sidebar to be the height of the page which could vary based on content along with possible conditions like a min-height. You are setting the sidebar to a set height here. If a user has to scroll five times to view all of the page's content the sidebar would be long gone by the time they got to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small example. Please review jsfiddle link below.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/whfukm5p/>
```

Comment: It Works, are how i can remove padding's? http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/05/479979974461ba730f3f15cb0ef1c7c1.png

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle live example? So I can guide you properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a navigation that is fixed rather than float.

`aside,
    .side-nav {
       width: 250px;
       margin-right: 15px;
       background-color: #2b2b2b;
       position: fixed;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       overflow: auto;
    }`

Height is a relative value based on the parent element, but since Window doesn't have a default height, relative height on elements can't be used.

If you insist in using relative height, you will need to set it via javascript or give it a default value.